# JS slice, split and parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, formatting, node-red

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero located outside with a DH22 temp/humidity sensor. This sensor is passing the reading via UDP, which is received by an UDP input node in NodeRed.

The data from the sensor is a string, in this format:

```
"(64.4000015258789, 14.899999618530273)"
```

I do not have much experience with JS, but I have learned a lot since starting with NodeRed. The message passed into the function is described: "The message is passed in as a JavaScript object called msg. By convention it will have a msg.payload property containing the body of the message."
After much try and error this is the code I think should work - but it doesn't...

```
var str = msg.payload;

var th = str.slice(0, -1);
th = th.split(",");

msg.payload[0] = parseFloat(th[0]);
msg.payload[1] = parseFloat(th[1]);

return [ msg.payload[0], msg.payload[1] ];
```

However, I get this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid' of ("
```

From the error message it seems that I'm trying to assign a value to the first character of msg.payload (msg.payload[0]) - which in this case is the character "(". I am somewhat comfused.

Edit:
In NodeRed I'm using a function node with two outputs. So the input string as mentioned should be stripped, split and parsed to float, and then be returned to each of the outputs. To send the data to the two different outputs, you do:

```
return [ data1, data2 ]
```

Data1 to output 1 and data2 to output 2.

Comment: Couldn't you replace all of that with `return JSON.parse(msg.payload)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think `msg.payload` here is "(64.4000015258789, 14.899999618530273)" and cannot be parsed as JSON.

Comment: Gives me this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". Not sure where the "o" comes from, because I verifed the raw output from the sensor and there is no "o".

Comment: @shaochuancs ah yes, how unhelpful.

Comment: In that case an alternative would be to use regular expressions to extract the numbers: `msg.payload.match(/\d+\.\d+/g).map(parseFloat)`.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question krizlybear; please see my last comment (at this time) under my answer - which should help you out. I will properly update my answer in a couple of hours, but **must** log off until then.

Comment: I will check it out! Appreciating the help!

Comment: @krizlybear - Reading [this documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi) (but having no access to the hard-or-software discussed) it looks as though `outputs` might be expecting `x` and `y` properties. Try `return { "x": arr[ 0 ], "y": arr[ 1 ] };` I'm afraid I may not be able to help much more than this as the error I have no way to debug the error from here.

Comment: [This IBM documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/iot-temperature-and-moisture-sensor-integrated-to-node-red-and-bluemix-ibm/) appears to suggest that the return should be an object literal too, but not with `"x"` or `"y"` properties.

Answer (score 3):

## Using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) inline

```js
var payload = "(64.4000015258789, 14.899999618530273)";

// remove the parentheses and split the remainder into an array
var arr = payload.replace( /[\(\)]/g, "" ).split( /\s*,\s*/ );

console.log( parseFloat( arr[ 0 ] ) );
console.log( parseFloat( arr[ 1 ] ) );
```

The [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\s*,\s*/` in `split()` will split the string at `","` and `", "`; it handles the possibility of there being arbitrary quantities of spaces before and/or after the comma.
The effect is that the resulting array values are automatically [trimmed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

### Reason for error in OP code

[JS `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes two parameters:

> `begin` Optional
>   Zero-based index at which to begin extraction.
>   A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(-2) extracts the last two elements in the sequence.
>   If begin is undefined, slice begins from index 0.
>
> `end` Optional
>   Zero-based index before which to end extraction. slice extracts up to but not including end.
>   For example, slice(1,4) extracts the second element through the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).
>   A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. slice(2,-1) extracts the third element through the second-to-last element in the sequence.
>   If end is omitted, slice extracts through the end of the sequence (arr.length).
>   If end is greater than the length of the sequence, slice extracts through the end of the sequence (arr.length).

```js
var foo = "(value, value)";

console.log( foo.slice( 0, -1 ) ); // "(value, value"

console.log( foo.slice( 1, -1 ) ); // "value, value"
```

### After reading some documentation

I think the code below **may** work. It is only a best guess based on limited examination and zero experience.

```
var arr = msg.payload.slice( 1, -1 ).split( /\s*,\s*/ );

msg.payload = { "value_name_1": arr[ 0 ], "value_name_2: arr[ 1 ] };
// or
msg.payload = arr;

return msg;
```

In the following 2 documents, code examples `return msg;` after modifying the `payload` property of it.

- [ibm.com - IoT temperature and moisture sensor integrated to Node-RED and Bluemix IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/iot-temperature-and-moisture-sensor-integrated-to-node-red-and-bluemix-ibm/)
- [rs-online.com - DESIGNSPARK - Home automation with Raspberry Pi 2 and Node-RED](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/home-automation-with-raspberry-pi-2-and-node-red)

This seems to be how *it's* done.

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape parentheses inside a character class.

Comment: I see. But when I do 'return parseFloat( arr[ 0 ] );' for example, I get error: '"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid of 52.5"'.

Comment: @krizlybear - That would depend on the rest of your code. A "read only property" cannot be changed, it is just for getting data. `msg.payload` appears to be "read only". You may have to build a new set of data, rather than rebuild the one you retrieve. Where are you trying to `return` the data to; what is the end result you're after? Add this info to your question.

Comment: @krizlybear - If you don't need to modify `msg.payload`, you can use the established values directly in your `return` like `return [ arr[0], arr[1] ];` **but** that's building a 2 value array from an array with 2 values, **so** it is simplest to just `return arr;`

Comment: Thanks for that last comment on slice! However, it still gets "TypeError trying to assign read only property '_msgid' of 51.0909". I have updated the question. The node receiving the data is for making a graphical representation of the data.

Comment: @krizlybear - updated with best guess solution and links to docs.

Comment: @Fred Gandt - Again, I really appreciate the effort to help me! I will try this right now. But first, take a look at the setup: [node](http://i.imgur.com/O9onM5I.png). You don't differentiate which output gets what data element in the array with the code you have there. See: [node2](http://i.imgur.com/3t6QgHV.png), which is a previous project of mine. I use: `if (msg.payload === "turnon") {
   return [ msg, null ];
} else if (msg.payload === "turnoff"){
   return [ null, msg ];
}`

Comment: Thanks to your help, and some further research I found that: `return [ { payload:msg.payload.humid } , { payload:msg.payload.temp } ];`, returns my two values out the two different outputs.

Comment: @krizlybear - Well ok. That's not a configuration I'd have guessed! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a problem on the usage of `slice` and `split`.

The code below:

```
var th = str.slice(0, -1);
th = th.split(",");
```

should be changed to:

```
var th = str.slice(1,-1).split(', ')
```

If the first parameter of `.slice()` is `0`, the result string would begin with "(", which introduce `TypeError` eventually.